# set state memory leak

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in flutter , i wrote a code that calls json data from api and then i executed but the execution became slow a little bit , and in console i found an error message that says

```
E/flutter ( 6908): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState#559ce(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 6908): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 6908): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 6908): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 6908): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1208:9)
E/flutter ( 6908): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1243:6)
E/flutter ( 6908): #2      _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState.getPlayer (package:footyappp/Fantazyy/players_creation_details_view.dart:101:5)
E/flutter ( 6908): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6908): #3      _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState.getClubIds.<anonymous closure> (package:footyappp/Fantazyy/players_creation_details_view.dart:84:14)
E/flutter ( 6908): #4      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1244:30)
E/flutter ( 6908): #5      _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState.getClubIds (package:footyappp/Fantazyy/players_creation_details_view.dart:73:5)
E/flutter ( 6908): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 6908): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 6908): #8      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
```

Here the code i have tried:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/Playerrs.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/club_api.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/create_team_view.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player%20copy.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player_lab.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Key/Key.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PlayersCreationDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Playerr> selectedPlayers;
  final int playerIndex;

  const PlayersCreationDetailsView ({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedPlayers,
    @required this.playerIndex
  })  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState createState() => _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState();
}


class _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState extends State<PlayersCreationDetailsView> {
  bool _sortAsc = false;
  int _sortColumnIndex = 0;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;
  PlayersDataSource _playersDataSource;
  List<Playerr> _players = [];
  List<ClubApi> selectedClubs = [];
  List<int> clubIdentifiers = [];
  List<Playerrs> playersjson = [];
  List<Playerr> playersApi = [];
    List<dynamic> playerList ;
   List _table;


  int _rowsPerPage = 20;
   final String apiUrl =
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39";
  
  static const headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    //Always make sure to check the api key and the limit of a request in a free api
    'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key
  };

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _playersDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAsc = ascending ;
    });
  }


  Future<void> getClubIds() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/teams?season=2020&league=39",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
          'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      selectedClubs = table
          .map((dynamic item) => ClubApi.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in selectedClubs){
         clubIdentifiers.add(item.team.id);
      }

      for(var item in clubIdentifiers){
        print("club id"+item.toString());
        this.getPlayer(item);
      }

    });

  }


  Future<void> getPlayer(int id) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39&team=$id",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      playersjson = table
          .map((dynamic item) => Playerrs.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in playersjson){
        String pos = item.statistics[0].games.position.toString().substring(9);
        playersApi.add(Playerr(item.player.id,item.player.firstname, item.player.lastname, pos,
            item.statistics[0].team.name,item.statistics[0].games.rating, item.statistics[0].games.appearences,item.statistics[0].goals.total,
            item.statistics[0].goals.assists,item.statistics[0].goals.conceded,
            item.statistics[0].cards.red, item.statistics[0].cards.yellow));
      }
      print(playersApi.length);
      // for(var item in playersApi){
      //   print("position"+item.position.toString());
      // print(item.position.contains("DEFENDER"));
      // }
      for(var item in playersApi){
        print("position"+item.position.toString());

      }
      if (widget.playerIndex < 2) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player

            .position.contains("GOALKEEPER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 7) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("DEFENDER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 12) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("MIDFIELDER")).toList();
      } else {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("ATTACKER")).toList();
      }

      print("length of selected"+widget.selectedPlayers.length.toString());
     for(var item in widget.selectedPlayers){
       print("selected"+item.toString());
       if(item == null){
         print("hello");
       }else if(item !=null){
         print(item.playerID.toString());
         _players.removeWhere((player) => player.playerID == item.playerID);
       }
     }
      //  widget.selectedPlayers.forEach((selectedPlayer) =>
      //     _players.removeWhere((player) => (player.playerID == selectedPlayer.playerID) && (selectedPlayer.playerID != null)));
      //  print("length of selected"+widget.selectedPlayers.length.toString());
      //filter out players who are already selected

        // for (Playerr player in widget.selectedPlayers) {
        //   _players.remove(player);
        // }
        _playersDataSource = PlayersDataSource(widget.playerIndex, widget.selectedPlayers, _players, context);

    });

  }

@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getClubIds();
    //filter out players by position

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(playersApi.length);

    return  playersApi.length == 0
        ? Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
            Color(0xFFe70066),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
        : WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PaginatedDataTable(
              columnSpacing: 1.0,
              horizontalMargin: 1.0,
              availableRowsPerPage: [10,20,50],
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) { setState(() { _rowsPerPage = value; }); },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAsc,
              header: Text("Players"),
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("First Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.firstName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Last Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.lastName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Position", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                  new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Price")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.price, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Rating", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.rating, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Position")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Team")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.team, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.appearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
              
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.points, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Week Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.pointsWeek, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
               
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Sub Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.subAppearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Goals")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.goals, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Assists")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.assists, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Clean")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.cleanSheets, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Yellows")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.yellowCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Reds")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.redCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               
              ],
              source: _playersDataSource,
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class PlayersDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  PlayersDataSource(this._playerIndex, this._selectedPlayers, this._players, this.context);

  int _playerIndex;
  List<Playerr> _players;
  List<Playerr> _selectedPlayers;

  int _selectedCount = 0;
  var context;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), bool ascending) {
    _players.sort((Playerr a, Playerr b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Playerr c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DataCell getCell(String text) {
    return DataCell(Container(width: _columnPosWidth, child: Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false,)));
  }

  


  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _players.length)
      return null;
    final Playerr player = _players[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      onSelectChanged: (bool) {
        _players.removeAt(index);
        _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {return CreateTeamView(players: _players, selectedPlayers: _selectedPlayers,);}));
      },
        index: index,
        cells: <DataCell>[
          getCell(player.firstName),
          getCell(player.lastName),
          getCell(player.position),
         getCell('${player.price}'),
          getCell('${player.rating}'),
         // getCell('${player.isFresher}'),
          getCell('${player.team}'),
          //getCell('${player.points}'),
         // getCell('${player.pointsWeek}'),
          getCell('${player.appearances}'),
         // getCell('${player.subAppearances}'),
          getCell('${player.goals}'),
          getCell('${player.assists}'),
          getCell('${player.cleanSheets}'),
         // getCell('${player.motms}'),
          getCell('${player.yellowCards}'),
          getCell('${player.redCards}'),
        //  getCell('${player.ownGoals}'),
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _players.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;


}
```

so the problem also the list of players that have position ATTACKER : not all of them is showing in the list maybe because of the set state or maybe something else ,

I am trying to find a solution for this problem of set state and filter, i am betting those problems are connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setState((){})` after page is closed and `dispose()` was called, you can use `mounted` property which is a boolean and check whether State object is currently in a tree, or in other words page is still active before calling `setState((){})`

```
  if(mounted){
      setState((){})
    }
```

Comment: in which setState should i put this property?? i used setState in a lot of places

Comment: Everywhere where setState is called in async function